# Sankey diagram using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, sankey-diagram

I want to draw a Sankey diagram using Action Script. Can anyone provide some direction regarding the algorithms or libraries that are available for this?

Comment: You could embed Google's javascript implementation within a native StageWebView :  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey , there are lots of javascript versions out there but I personally do not know of an existing one in ActionScript

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is not AIR app, it is a web application and StageWebView is not available for that

Answer (score 0):

For that I would suggest you to use [d3 library](http://d3js.org/) to draw your [Sankey diagram](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) and overlay the diagram above the Flash Player using CSS tricks.

If you instead want to show the diagram as image inside the Flash Player itself, then you can render the diagram inside a hidden HTML5 Canvas and load its dataURL as an image source. Use [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get dataURL from HTML5 Canvas.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ExternalInterface.call("CanvasToDataURL")); //js function to get DataURL.
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request); 
addChild(loader);
```

Also do some research, as I have not tested my answer yet.